# (can only concatenate str (not "int") to str) when using One-hot encoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, multiclass-classification

I'm trying to build a multi-classification neural network from scratch but One_hot function is not working, could you help me to solve it?

```
def one_hot(Y):
    one_hot_y=np.zeros((Y.size,Y.max() +1))
    one_hot_y[np.arange(Y.size), Y] = 1
    one_hot_y = one_hot_y.T
    return one_hot_y
```

This is the type of error I get when I run the neural network function

[image: Error]

Comment: I guess `Y` contains strings. What `Y.max() + 1` supposed to be?

Comment: Apparently, `Y.max()` is a string

Comment: Try ```int(Y.max()) + 1```

Answer (score 1):

Check the data types in Y, my bet is that you have strings in there.
Python prevents you from doing the operation "str + int", hence causing the issue at `Y.max() + 1` on the first line